# Mysql get value from table B if not excist in table A or the other way arround

Tags: mysql, join, concatenation

There might be a simple solution for this one, but I can't find the right syntax to find the answer in my search.
The stored info was kept in an old table but in time there is a new table that stores the info now. So I need to get the info from the old table if it is not present in the new table

GIVEN :
I have 2 tables : properties & information
table properties has a field called "value". 
This table also has a field with a number in another column which allows me to grab only the info matching this number(ex: get the value where number is 35)
table information has a field called "pbxinfo".
Both values inside these columns are the same, only column names are different.

WANTED:
I need an output that fills in a column (ex name:resultinfo) in the result of the query.
The output should then be something like :

```
CUSTOMER                 RESULTINFO

mister b                 08/2007  (value from properties)
misses A                 03/2015  (value from information)
junior K                 05/2011  (value from information)
baby June                04/2017  (value from properties)
....
```

so some of the info comes from table A and some of the info comes from table B, depending where the value is found.

Who can help me with this one?

tnx in advance !

Comment: It would be more better if you give example of your tables properties & information, rather than the explanation. It's difficult to understand.

Comment: ok... this was far more easier than anticipated. A simple COALESCE did the job for me.
Just had to add (in the select part) following line :
COALESCE(properties.value, information.value) and add a LEFT JOIN for one of the tables..